# Everyday objects

Tags: riddle

This after dinner riddle takes time to solve

I got five of that one,

Just two of another

Only one for the none

And all of the others.

For my old version

I got 5 of that five

Just 4 for the ten

Total 17 of I to have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are a

> CLOCK! (e.g. circular analog wall clock for example)

You have

> 5 1's (at 1, 10, 11, 12)
>  2 2's (at 2, 12)
>  1 of each other digit 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Your old version is a

> CLOCK WITH ROMAN NUMERALS

You have

> 5 V's (at IV, V, VI, VI, VIII)
>  4 X's (at IX, X, XI, XII)
>  and 17 I's !

These are everyday objects and they

> take *time* to solve!

Comment: Mine has 13 1's, 8 2's, 3 each of 3 and 4, and 2 of all the rest...

Comment: A benford's sample?

Comment: @TSLF rot13(gjragl-sbhe ubhe pybpx).